# Manejar posibles errores en campos de tipo date

Tags: javascript, html5, ecmascript-6

Buen dia, Estoy trabajando con javascript vanilla y quiero hacer un campo de prestamos de libro donde el usuario se le entregara un libro por X dias y se debe de mostrar la fecha en la que el lo presto y la fecha estimada de entrega

```js
const addZero = (i) => {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
};

const getdate = () => {
  let date = new Date();

  let dd = date.getDate();
  let mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  dd = addZero(dd);
  mm = addZero(mm);

  return yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
};

const addEndReserve = (datestart, days) => {
  let dateparts = datestart.split("-").map((d) => parseInt(d));

  let day = dateparts[2] + days;
  let month = dateparts[1];
  let year = dateparts[0];

  day = addZero(day);
  month = addZero(month);

  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
};

let fechahoy = getdate()
console.log(addEndReserve(fechahoy, 25))
```

Y como pueden ver al sumarle 25 dias a la fecha de hoy(08/09/2020), me dice que la entrega sera 2020-09-33, cuando deberia de ser 2020-10-03, nose como evitar ese error, para que al hacer una reserva me diga la fecha correcta.

Comment: trabajar con fechas en un javascript puro se hace demasiado complejo, yo te recomendaria que uses una libreria llamada momentJS que se encarga de manejar fechas, tienes varios idiomas disponibles y con solo unas pocas lineas de codigo tengas el resultado que buscas

Comment: @Enzo gracias amigo, pero el ejercicio es en js vanilla :(.  pero gracias por recomendarme la libreria momentJS la verdad no la conocia, me servira para proyectos futuros!!

Comment: de nada, para eso estamos,para ayudarnos, todos empezamos por algo y nadie nació sabiendo todo, para futuros proyectos hay muchas librerías que te ahorrarían muchísimo tiempo a la hora de crear aplicaciones tanto como nativas, web o de escritorios, no dudes en preguntar.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más fácil seria crear un objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) y dejar que este se encargue de calcular la fecha.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const addZero = (i) => {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
};

const getdate = () => {
  let date = new Date();

  let dd = date.getDate();
  let mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  dd = addZero(dd);
  mm = addZero(mm);

  return yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
};

const addEndReserve = (datestart, days) => {
  let dateparts = datestart.split("-").map((d) => parseInt(d));

  let day = dateparts[2];
  let month = dateparts[1];
  let year = dateparts[0];
  
  // -- 
  // ACA Creamos el objeto Date para obtener la fecha
  let date = new Date(year, month - 1, day + days);
  day = date.getDate();
  month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  year = date.getFullYear();
  // --

  day = addZero(day);
  month = addZero(month);

  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
};

let fechahoy = getdate()
console.log(addEndReserve(fechahoy, 25))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!, funciona de maravilla